# ASP.NET MVC ActionMailer Email Layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, actionmailer

With ActionMailer, can a layout page be specified for a view to use? If so, should the layout page be a regular cshtml view or does it also need to be html.cshtml / txt.cshtml?

I've commented out some of the lines where I tried specifying the layout, but it did not work.

**MailController**

```
public EmailResult Welcome(User userInfo)
    {
        /*Create ViewModel*/
        To = "user@email.com";
        From = "test@email.com";
        Subject = "Welcome!";

        /*return Email("Welcome",welcomeVM,"EmailLayout",true);*/
        return Email("Welcome", welcomeVM);
    }
```

**Welcome.html.cshtml**

```
@model WelcomeVM
{
    //Layout = "EmailLayout"
    Layout = null;
}

@*Email Contents Here*@
```

Comment: Are you using this lib? https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide

Comment: No this is `ActionMailer` http://nuget.org/packages/ActionMailer/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm used to the [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide) lib. However, try specifying a Layout page this way:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MyLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Just make sure the layout page exists in the path specified.

From [ActionMailer's doc page](https://bitbucket.org/swaj/actionmailer.net/wiki/Home) in step 2, it mentions that it's possible to use Layouts:

> Now we need to create a View for this email. The view can use any
>   ViewEngine you like, and it will even work with master pages (or
>   layouts in Razor). The views live in the same place your normal views
>   do.